# how to write micrometer squared per cubic meter in plot label in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to write micrometer square/cubic meter in my plot `label` in ggplot and I got an error when I add m^2.  The first expression is ok but it's missing the ^2.  My attempt to add m^2 did not work because I did not see the superscript.

1. `ylab (expression(paste("Surface area concentration (",mu,"m/",m^3,")", sep="")))`
2. `ylab (expression(paste("Surface area concentration (",mu,",m^2,"/,m^3,")", sep="")))`

Thank you

Comment: Please note that using sep="" in plotmath `paste()` expressions is _just wrong_. That function is not the same as the character `paste` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is just a quote problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + 
ylab (expression(paste(
  "Surface area concentration (",
  mu, m^2, "/", m^3,
  ")", sep="")))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 qplot(0, ylab = ~ "Surface area concentration ( " * mu * m^2 / m^3 * ")")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, even shorter:

```
plot(0, ylab = ~ "Surface area concentration" (mu * m^2 / m^3))
plot(0, ylab = Surface~area~concentration (mu * m^2 / m^3))
```